# Powershell: How to add Result to an Array (ForEach-Object -Parallel)

Tags: powershell

I know, that with the Parameter `$using:foo` I can use a Variable from a different runspace while running `ForEach-Object -Parallel` in Powershell 7 and up.

But how can I add the result back to a Variable? The common parameters `+=` and `$using:` will not work.

**For instance:**

```
$AllSubs = Get-AzSubscription
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$Costs = @()

$AllSubs | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Set-AzContext $_.Name | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Fetching Costs from '$($_.Name)' ..."
    $using:Costs += Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $using:Date -EndDate $using:Date -IncludeAdditionalProperties -IncludeMeterDetails -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

**Output:**

```
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is
     | able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to split the operation into two and assign the reference you get from `$using:Costs` to a local variable, and you will have to use a different data type than PowerShell's resizable array - preferably a *concurrent* (or *thread-safe*) type:

```
$AllSubs = Get-AzSubscription
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

# Create thread-safe collection to receive output
$Costs = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[psobject]]::new()

$AllSubs | Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Set-AzContext $_.Name | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Fetching Costs from '$($_.Name)' ..."

    # Obtain reference to the bag with `using` modifier 
    $localCostsVariable = $using:Costs

    # Add to bag
    $localCostsVariable.Add($(Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $using:Date -EndDate $using:Date -IncludeAdditionalProperties -IncludeMeterDetails -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering, does this type of collection work on jobs / runspace?

Comment: The wiring will be different (you'd use a SessionStateProxy variable to provide the reference to the collection), but sure

Comment: Nicely done. An alternative to using a local variable is to enclose the `$using:` reference in `(...)`: `($using:Costs).Add(...)`. Arguably, neither should be necessary - see [GitHub issue #10876](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10876)