# Variable returns empty when using foreach-object -parallel

Tags: powershell, loops, parallel-processing, foreach-object

I want to calculate something in a foreach-object -parallel loop and return a variable, but it keeps returning empty!

For example, I have this simple script and would like to read $sum at the end.

```
$numbers = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
$sum = 0
$numbers | foreach-object -parallel {
     $sum += $_ 
}  
Write-Host $sum
```

When it leaves the loop $sum is empty  How can I keep the value?   Some is talking about $using: but I cannot get that to work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75251848/how-do-i-add-an-atomic-counter-to-a-powershell-foreach-parallel-loop/75252238#75252238 you can't update a value type from multiple threads, it must be a reference type. You also need to ensure there is a locking mechanism in place when doing so

Comment: To add to Santiago's comment: A simple solution is to _output_ values and act on them outside the parallel script block, along the lines of `$sum = (ForEach-Object -Parallel { $_ + 1 }  | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum`

Answer (score 0):

The script block with -Parallel switch which run the script block parallelly on separate process threads, so when its in the loop the sum of array will be calculated like below

```
thread 1: $sum (0) + $numbers[0] (1) = 1
thread 2: $sum (0) + $numbers[1] (2) = 2
thread 3: $sum (0) + $numbers[2] (3) = 3
thread 4: $sum (0) + $numbers[3] (4) = 4
thread 5: $sum (0) + $numbers[4] (5) = 5
```

Then returns the $sum variable value which assigned out of the script block.
I don't think you can calculate the value and return out of the script block when using parallel switch, but if you find a way, please do update here.
Here are some examples without parallel switch:

```
1.. 100 | ForEach-Object -begin {$sum=0 }-process {$sum+=$_} -end {"The total of the numbers input is $sum"}

$(for($i=0;$i -le 100; $i+=5){$i} ) | ForEach-Object -begin {$sum=0 }-process {$sum+=$_} -end {"The sum by fives of the numbers input is $sum"}
```

Thank you