Foreach-Object -Parallel - Export-csv Issue
Help required for Foreach-Object -Parallel Export-csv issue
1)Unable to export pscustom object data to csv, below is the code.
2)Unable to increment value in the $i++ to see the number of users processed.
$count = $users1.Count
$i=0
$users1 = $users | select -First 10
$data = $Users1 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $i++
    Write-Host ("Processing user {0} -> {1}/{2}." -f $_.UserPrincipalName, ($using:i), $using:count)
    $AuthMethods = Get-MgUserAuthenticationMethod -UserId $_.Id
    $Methods = $AuthMethods.AdditionalProperties.'@odata.type' | Select-Object -Unique
    $phoneNumber = $emailaddress = $null
    ForEach ($Method in $Methods){
        Switch ($Method) {
            "#microsoft.graph.phoneAuthenticationMethod"{
            $phoneNumber = $AuthMethods.AdditionalProperties.phoneNumber -join ";"}
            "#microsoft.graph.emailAuthenticationMethod"{
            $emailaddress = $AuthMethods.AdditionalProperties.emailAddress -join ";"}
        } #Switch
    }  #nested foreach method
    $ReturnObject += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    User   = $_.UserPrincipalName
    PhoneNumbers = $phoneNumber
    emailaddress = $emailaddress}
} -ThrottleLimit 5
$data | Export-Csv "c:\temp\authreport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append


Not sure why you trying doing this piece in parallel. If it is to gain performance and you comparing this to something that initially used += to build a collection (as in one of your previous questions), then the first thing I would advice you is try avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection as it is inefficiënt.

$ReturnObject += New-Object PSObject -Property @{

You are storing the results in an array called $ReturnObject without returning it from your foreach block or accessing it. Just remove that bit and your example should work:
New-Object PSObject -Property @{

This will return each new object and add it to $data

thank you so much, can you also help me with increment i++ is not working it is returning as
Processing user P-> 0/10.
Processing user R-> 0/10.
Processing user Mr-> 0/10.
Processing user Jva-> 0/10.
Processing user Jrk-> 0/10.
Processing user Dcom -> 0/10.
Processing user Mza-> 0/10.
Processing user M-> 0/10.
Processing user ab -> 0/10.
Processing user cd-> 0/10.

@dss.pisces incrementing a value from multiple threads will make your code less efficient however if you still want to do this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75251848/how-do-i-add-an-atomic-counter-to-a-powershell-foreach-parallel-loop and $i++ is supported in powershell.
