"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when calling method on NoteProperty added in parallel processing
I'm trying to add an object of a class as a NoteProperty to another class inside a ForEach-Object -Parallel block in PowerShell 7. However, when I try to call a method on that added NoteProperty, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
class test {}

$test = [test]::New()

1..2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
    class test2 {
        testmethod () {
            Write-Host "test method called"
        }
    }
    Add-Member -InputObject $using:test -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "property$_" -Value ([test2]::New())
}

$test.property1.testmethod() 

If I do a Get-Member on $test.property1 I get the method testmethod in the output.
I understand that the issue might be related to how objects and properties are scoped within the parallel block. How can I correctly add the NoteProperty and ensure that the method call works outside the parallel block?
The error I get:

Get-Member on $test.property1:

It works with simple ForEach-Object without -Parallel.

Please copy and paste the error message and member information into the question as text. No pictures.

Redefining a custom class (in your case class test2 { ... } inside every iteration of your parallel foreach) has some known issues - see for example https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8767 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20893.
It's likely this is another symptom of the same underlying problem.
One workaround would be to declare your class in the parent scope - if you do this you'll find there's an immediate issue in that the parallel foreach can't access that type in its scope and you get a Unable to find type [test2] error:
# broken code - don't use (see next code sample for a workaround)

class test {}

class test2 {
    testmethod () {
        Write-Host "test method called"
    }
}

$test = [test]::New()

1..2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
    Add-Member -InputObject $using:test -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "property$_" -Value ([test2]::New())
}

# Unable to find type [test2].

But a follow-up workaround is to capture a reference to the type in a variable and then use the $using scope modifier to access it:
class test {}

class test2 {
    testmethod () {
        Write-Host "test method called"
    }
}
$test2 = [test2]
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

$test = [test]::New()

1..2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
    Add-Member -InputObject $using:test -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "property$_" -Value (($using:test2)::New())
    # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

$test.property1.testmethod()

which gives the output
test method called


Update
It wasn't part of your original question, but be aware that you'll need to ensure your parallel code is thread-safe - if multiple foreach -parallel iterations try to run Add-Member concurrently you may get unpredictable results.
@SantiagoSquarzon has a good answer outlining some options for coordinating across multiple threads in PowerShell here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75252238/3156906

Suggesting adding a lock on $using:test to make it thread safe

@SantiagoSquarzon - good point. I've added a short update and pointed to one of your previous answers :-)


To add to mclayton's helpful answer:
Using ForEach-Object -Parallel (available in PowerShell (Core) 7 only) comes with several challenges:

Each parallel thread runs in a separate runspace, which, in essence, is an  independent PowerShell session that knows nothing about the caller's state.

The latter is the reason that any of the caller's variable (values) must be referenced via the $using: scope.


Due to parallel execution, you may have to perform explicit synchronization between the runspaces (threads) to avoid race conditions or state corruption.

Due to the latter's complexity - see this answer for a discussion and solutions - it is generally best to avoid cross-runspace (cross-thread) modification of data.


An additional challenge comes with cross-runspace use of PowerShell custom classes, as in your case:

PowerShell class instances by default have runspace affinity (i.e., they're tied to a specific runspace) and trying to invoke their members from a different runspace can lead to state corruption, with symptoms ranging from subtle bugs to outright errors, such as in your case.

[scriptblock] literals ({ ... }) too have runspace affinity, and in their case ForEach-Object -Parallel explicitly prevents their cross-runspace use;[1] e.g.,
$sb = { 'hi!' }; % -Parallel { & $using:sb } triggers the following error:
A ForEach-Object -Parallel using variable cannot be a script block [...]






PowerShell 7.4+ offers a way to create classes without runspace affinity, which can then safely be used from any runspace, namely via the
[NoRunspaceAffinity()] attribute.
The following solution:

demonstrates use of [NoRunspaceAffinity()]
avoids the need for synchronization by handling the ETS property decoration via (Add-Member) outside the ForEach-Object -Parallel block, in an additional, regular ForEach-Object call where no concurrency issues can arise.

Note:

This is largely for illustration, as in real life you wouldn't be defining a class inside a ForEach-Object -Parallel call, because not only is a class then defined in each parallel runspace, all resulting classes are then distinct .NET types.

class test {}

$test = [test]::New()

1..2 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    # Define the class without runspace affinity, so its instance
    # can safely be used in other runspaces, notably the caller's.
    [NoRunspaceAffinity()]
    class test2 {
        testmethod () {
            Write-Host "test method called"
        }
    }
    # Output an custom object with the target property name
    # and an instance of the [test2] class
    [pscustomobject] @{
        Name = "Property$_"
        Value = [test2]::New()
    }
} | ForEach-Object {
    # Attach an ETS NoteProperty member based on each runspace's output.
    Add-Member -InputObject $test -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
}

# OK - the [test2] instances stored as property values can now
# be safely accessed.
$test.property1.testmethod()
$test.property2.testmethod()


[1] By contrast, creating a script block from a string, using [scriptblock]::Create(), creates an unbound [scriptblock] instance, which runs in whatever runspace it is called from; however, ForEach-Object -Parallel's refusal to use a script block via $using: is categorical.
